# Compression Ratio of an image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, compression, fft, image-compression

I was trying to calculate the CR(compressing ratio) of an image that I compressed and decompressed using FFT in matlab. I have read a similar post here about CR calculation but I did not get the method he was using to process the image. That post was saying that :  CR = numel(X)/numel(Y)
What I understood is that X is my image before FFT and Y is after. So I said that

```
I=imread('flowers.tif')
RGB = im2double(I);
%process...
iRGB = my reconstructed image after iFFT
CR = numel(RGB)/numel(iRGB);
```

But this results in CR =1 which I do not think that is the correct answer. Can someone explain to me what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compression rate is the ratio of `numel` of the **compressed** representation and the un-compressed one. Your `iRGB` is a **reconstructed** representation and therefore has the same number of elements as `RGB` (you need to reconstruct the entire  image). For the CR you need the `numel` of your **compressed** representation.

Comment: So I need to hold a matrix with the masks (the channels with the remaining frequencies which I send to ifft) and call `numel` with it?

Comment: @Saraki it's a bit more complicated than that. You need to count the number of bytes you actually need to represent an image in your settings. If you have a mask then you need to somehow represent it as well as the information in the unmasked locations.